# Isn't it wrong to say Parent-Child tables in database design?

Tags: foreign-keys, parent-child, relationship, rdbms

I am learning database designing and got acquainted with basic terminologies like `ER diagrams`, `relationships between Entities` etc.

I came across terms like `Parent , child tables`. It is these terminologies where I am not able to understand; I did search similar questions asked earlier in SO, but I am not still clear.

`Parent - Child` terminologies makes sense in `Object oriented` programming, where we literally have `parent - child classes`; how does this make sense in `RDBMS'?

Can anyone help me understand `parent - child table` relationship between tables in `RDBMS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms are so general that you have to figure out what is meant from context. There are parents & children when a relation(ship)/association describes a tree/hierarchy/network. It just means there is an edge from one node to another in some graph representation of some relationship. That includes diagrams with conceptually directed lines. Often the terms are used in a relational or information modeling context for the referenced & referencing tables in the meta-relation(ship)/association on tables that a parent table "is referenced by" a child table meaning there is a foreign key (FK) from the child to the parent. This is related to FKs wrongly being called "relationships". But *tables*/*relations* represent business/application relation(ship)s/associations on values (possibly identifying entities) in relational databases. Hence the "*Relational* Model" and the "Entity-*Relationship* Model".