# If a parent entity is SCD type 4 with a history table, should the child entities (one-to-many) also have a history table?

Tags: foreign-keys, versioning, scd

Lets say we have an entity `recipe (id, version, other_stuff)` with a child entity `ingredient (recipe_id, recipe_version, other_stuff)`. Any recipe can have multiple ingredients, and ingredients can only have one recipe.

We want to implement SCD Type 4 for recipes (thus the version columns above), and by extension the ingredients need to be part of the versioning system.

If we make a `recipe_history (id, version, other_stuff)` table that stores the old versions of the recipes, and don't make one for the ingredients, then the ingredients records have foreign keys to two tables - `recipe` and `recipe_history`.

But to my knowledge that is not possible in SQL. Is the only alternative to make a new table `ingredient_history`, and copy and all the ingredients for each old recipe version to this table?

One obvious downside to this is that you end up making copies of ingredients that may not have changed from version to version.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean, FKs to 2 tables? Why do you suspect you can't? Have you tried? You can have 2 FKs from the same referencing columns to different places. In the case that you can't do what you want, you are abusing the term "FK" & writing something that doesn't make sense. So describe what you want using other terms. Also even using "FK" it's not clear exactly what you want referencing what satisfying what condition. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Constrain subrows to be in (at least? exactly?) one of multiple other places?

Comment: Clearly when clearly expressed this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that you want historic recipes limited to referring to current ingedients, as a historic one could be missing now & historically invalid new ones could be present. PS "parent" & "child" are such generic terms that unless you define exactly how you are using them things can be unclear. Best to just avoid them. Eg in a FK context talk about referencing & referenced tables/entities. [Databases with Foreign Keys: Good way to picture forward vs. backward relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61390707/3404097)

Comment: What is your 1 question? PS Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking what the asker actually wants answered.

Comment: "an ingredient can only have one recipe"? Not in the real world.  Maybe you are misleadingly calling use of an ingredient in a recipe (after "order line", maybe a "recipe  line") an ingredient? And presumably you actually have a table of ingredients that are referenced from recipe lines. Maybe you have chosen an example domain & entities in place of your actual ones that are not clearly reflecting the nature of the relationship constraints?